# POST request XML with CakePHP

Tags: php, xml, cakephp, post

I'm trying to make a POST request of XML data with CakePHP 2.3.8, but I'm having some issues and I think it's dealing with authorization. First of all, what I'm trying to do is make a POST request with XML data from an action in a controller. The action which this post request is made to should save an entry in the database, just so I know that the POST request was successfully triggered. Nothing is being saved.

Here are the two actions and the beforefilter. I made sure to allow access to every action in the beforefilter. xml_post is the action that I visit which triggers the XML post request, and the receive_xml action is the one that should save an entry in the database when something is received.

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->authorize = 'Controller';  
    $this->Auth->allow = array('*');
}

public function xml_post_test(){
    $data = array(
        'post' => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'title' => 'This is a test',
            'body' => 'Here is something for the body '
        )
    );

    App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');
    $http = new HttpSocket();
    $xml_data = Xml::fromArray($data);
    $xml_string = $xml_data->asXML();
    $response = $http->post('http://localhost/tests/receive_xml', $xml_string);
    debug($response);
}

    //save an arbitrary entry in the database a POST request is received (just checking that the xml_post_test method is working
public function receive_xml(){
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            $this->loadmodel('TestTable');
            $this->TestTable->create();
            $this->TestTable->save(array('id' => '','data' => 'abc 123'));
        }
}
```

Here is the response (debug)

```
object(HttpSocketResponse) {
    body => ''
    headers => array(
        'Date' => 'Mon, 07 Apr 2014 02:28:15 GMT',
        'Server' => 'Apache/2.4.4 (Unix) PHP/5.4.19 OpenSSL/1.0.1e mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3',
        'X-Powered-By' => 'PHP/5.4.19',
        'Set-Cookie' => 'CAKEPHP=ddb8lvdvmqvrce9ve2eo5e61l5; expires=Mon, 07-Apr-2014 06:28:15 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly',
        'Location' => 'http://localhost/users/login',
        'Content-Length' => '0',
        'Connection' => 'close',
        'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
    )
    cookies => array(
        'CAKEPHP' => array(
            'value' => 'ddb8lvdvmqvrce9ve2eo5e61l5',
            'expires' => 'Mon, 07-Apr-2014 06:28:15 GMT',
            'path' => '/',
            'httponly' => true
        )
    )
    httpVersion => 'HTTP/1.1'
    code => '302'
    reasonPhrase => 'Found'
    raw => 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Mon, 07 Apr 2014 02:28:15 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.4 (Unix) PHP/5.4.19 OpenSSL/1.0.1e mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.19
Set-Cookie: CAKEPHP=ddb8lvdvmqvrce9ve2eo5e61l5; expires=Mon, 07-Apr-2014 06:28:15 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Location: http://localhost/users/login
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

'
    context => array()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see one problem without looking at details--

```
$this->Auth->allow = array('*');
```

should be as

```
$this->Auth->allow = array();
```

Answer (score 0):

The main thing you need to do is set the `Content-Type` header to `application/xml`. You may also wish to set the `Accept-Type` header to the same value (if you want XML responses without using the `Router::parseExtensions()` method where response types are inferred from the extension you pass in the URL).